# Can't get POST value from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can't get value of filter. Don't know why. Am I doing AJAX wrong?
For the record, I'm new to ajax and have looked many places, with many not getting real answers to the same issue.

**JQUERY: index.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'news.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {filter:'some value'},
    });
});
```

**HTML: index.php**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <? include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/news/news.php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP: news.php**

```
$sbFilter = $_POST['filter'];
echo "select* from test_table where status='3'and ('". $sbFilter."') ORDER BY  `test_table`.`date` DESC, nid DESC   limit 0 , 6"
```

**Console Log:**

**Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/news/news.php** on line **36**

**Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in **/home/news/news.php** on line **36**
**// HERE IS MY ECHO**
select* from test_table where status='3'and press<>1 and ('some value') ORDER BY  `test_table`.`date` DESC, nid DESC   limit 0 , 6
**Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/home/news/news.php** on line **42**

**Warning**:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/news/news.php

**On the page, I get:**

select* from test_table where status='3' and ('') ORDER BY  `test_table`.`date` DESC, nid DESC   limit 0 , 6

Comment: Yes, you're doing it wrong. What do you expect from your code?

Comment: Can you see if the request is actually being triggered? Use chrome , press F12 .When the developement tools open go to their settings and make sure you have checked "Log xmlhttprequests" . Then leave the console open and refresh the page to see your ajax call and copy paste the output here. Also i dont like that comma after 'some value'}

Comment: Looks fine, though... it will have no effect on the web page, you never did anything with the response.

Comment: I expect to get my value lol. But seriously, that value will be used in a mysqli query.

Comment: @ThomasNikoleris I dont see that option. I'm using firefox

Comment: @StevenSerrano Well since i said chrome that makes sense. I dont know where it is on firefox i dont use it. Also i dont think you understand what is suppose to happen. The ajax sents the post variable to a php script that php script indeed echos the value BUT you are not capturing the output with your ajax to show it to the screen. Try adding to the ajax ***i'll post as answer**

Comment: [jQuery AJAX Basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) demonstrates the Firebug/Firefox developer tools.

Comment: I'm curious @StevenSerrano how are you accessing this file, as `http://localhost` (or hosted), or directly in your browser as `file:///`? There is a big difference.

Comment: You have no success or error handler, so what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not looking at the right place to see if your php code is returning the correct value. Your AJAX request only asks for data, but does not do anything with it, you're not saving it in a variable, using it in a callback function or modifying your webpage.

You could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'news.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {filter:'some value'},
    }).done(function(data) {
         // Do something with your data here, say output to console
         console.log(data);
    });
});
```

This only outputs the server output to console, you're gonna have to do something else in order to see a change in your webpage. What you do here is up to you and what you want to see exactly.

You should be able to view the server response as well on the network tabs of whatever browser you use.

As for your question updates:

First off, you should be using mysqli functions, not mysql [as they are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).
In any case, you need to create a connection object, which evidently you're not using from your warning error ([see here for an example of both these points](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).
Most importantly, you're not sanitizing your inputs or using prepared statements (see the last link for an example with these). If you don't do this, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection.

As for your webpage not having any changes, you have two problems here:

1. You need to have your JS do something with server output.
2. You're not using mysqli correctly to perform queries.

The solution to 1 is modifying the console.log part of the callback function to modify a webpage.
The solution to 2 is using the MySQL php interface correctly.
To reiterate, please look into prepared statements and reformulate your queries, they're very important and a very simple element to implement for a comparatively big security boost.

Comment: I get a green dot indication "200 OK"

Comment: I changed the response to be more complete. Hopefully that's more helpful.

Comment: I've updated my question with more info. I seem to get my value in the log, but not on the page itself.

Comment: I originally replied with a  comment, but I've updated my answer accordingly since my comment grew too large.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax sents the post variable to a php script that php script indeed echos the value BUT you are not capturing the output with your ajax to show it to the screen. Try adding to the ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'news.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {filter: 'some value'}
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes sorry its a continuation of my comment. I will edit and paste it here

Comment: Please, [you shouldn't be using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I chose alert so he could not miss it. PS thanks for your comment on deleting my other answer

Comment: @ThomasNikoleris I've updated my question, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing it because you are sending the data as JSON. That's why your $_POST global is empty, to access POST data sent as JSON you need to do following:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))
```